# Animation that creates another instance if interruped

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, animation

I am making one of those idle/cicker games. Every time the user taps the screen I pulse an image (make it shrink then grow very quickly). I have a textview which starts out with an alpha of 0 and sets its value to the value I want displayed when it is shown.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="-6%p"
        android:duration="800" />

</set>
```

Here is my current code for executing the animation.

```
Animation plus = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.plus);
        plusText.startAnimation(plus);
        updateText();
        plus.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {}
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {}
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                plusText.setAlpha(0);
            }
        });
```

The problem is that if the user taps faster than the time alloded for the animation to complete, the animation stops and resets and you don't get to see the full animation. Is there a way that each time the user taps It will just layer another of the same animation on top without repeating?

Any help is extremely appreciated!